# How to get find_elements_by_class_name to work in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

url = "https://www.staples.ca/products/959340-en-dr-pepper-355-ml-cans-12-pack"

s=Service('C:/Users/teddy/OneDrive/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.get(url)
get_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name()
```

My Python IDE (Pycharm) shows the find_elements_by_class_name as crossed out like  driver.<s>find_elements_by_class_name</s> .  I thought it was because it was deprecated but that's the only recommendation it gives me when I type driver.find...  I did some Googling, tried findElement, find_Element, none of it seems to work.

Hopefully somebody will be able to help me.

Thanks

**Edit**:
Thanks everyone.  find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, name) works.  But, how do I pick up the price from the product in the Staples link?  If I'm not mistaken, the class should be 'money-details'.

And if I try to print(get_elements), I get <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="88110248d45906160075293767595b86", element="8bd5bb03-3dea-4a8d-b59e-976e6a4e19e1")>

What should I do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,..)` and see if the error persists.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, '//button')
```

Source: [Documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Selenium V3.0 series, it has support for both

```
get_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name()
```

or an equivalent

```
get_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "")
```

both should work.

Also, not exactly sure why you are facing that issue. Please clarify your Selenium, Python, driver version etc.

**Fix :**

You can try, explicit waits to have a list like this :

```
get_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "")))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are using Selenium 4. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py) you will see under `find_element_by_class_name` (or any other `find_element_by_*` method) a deprecation warning

```
warnings.warn(
    "find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead",
    DeprecationWarning,
    stacklevel=2,
)
```

I don't know why PyCharm didn't suggested it, but `find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)` will work for you.

Comment: that's an internal change. End-user will not get impacted cause of that. @Guy

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes, he would. You can even try it yourself.

Comment: Besides, if it was internal only I doubt the developers would have bothered with deprecation warnings, they would simply remove the method.